# Can dual-sim phone use one sim for voice\sms and second solely for internet access?

Tags: dual-sim

Is it possible with dual-SIM Android phone to use one SIM-card for voice and SMS but not internet access and second solely for internet access? I tried reading PDF manuals for such phones but it's a bit unclear.

I'm moving abroad for work and will need to keep my current work SIM to communicate with the main office but I'd also like to use a local operator to access internet because it's going to be way too expensive to continue to use internet via my work SIM abroad. And I really don't like to carry a second phone or portable router for this. Looking at HTC One Dual sim at the moment, looks good but I never used dual-SIM phones before and have no idea how those actually work. Will it be able to function the way I need it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Both sim can be used for internet and voice calls. You can also select which sim can be used for internet and which can be used for voice calls.The settings can be found under `Settings-> Wireless & networks`.